setup script for more than one component from one place - Nuxt3
i use Nuxt3
I have an /components/icons folder
Inside the /components/icons there are many icons :

/components/icons/apps.vue
/components/icons/arrow-up.vue
/components/icons/bookmark.vue
/components/icons/home.vue
/components/icons/edit.vue

The icons are in svg format and I want to write, for example, this code for all these icons without repeating them in each file.
Example of any icon file :
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  size: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
});

const svg = ref();
const size = ref(props.size);

onMounted(() => {
  if (!size.value) {
    size.value = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(svg.value).fontSize);
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <svg
    ref="svg"
    :width="size"
    :height="size"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
      d="M3.35288 9.7093C4.00437 6.92879 6.17301 4.75775 8.95043 4.10553C10.9563 3.6345 13.0437 3.6345 15.0496 4.10553C17.827 4.75775 19.9956 6.92879 20.6471 9.70931C21.1176 11.7174 21.1176 13.8072 20.6471 15.8152C19.9956 18.5957 17.827 20.7668 15.0496 21.419C13.0437 21.89 10.9563 21.89 8.95044 21.419C6.17301 20.7668 4.00437 18.5957 3.35288 15.8152C2.88237 13.8072 2.88237 11.7174 3.35288 9.7093Z"
      fill="#363853"
      fill-opacity="0.15"
      stroke="#363853"
      stroke-width="1.5" />
    <path
      d="M14.5 12.7622H9.5M12 15.265L12 10.2595"
      stroke="#363853"
      stroke-width="1.5"
      stroke-linecap="round" />
  </svg>
</template>


I don't want to repeat this code in every icon,
Also when calling icons it is by default like this and I do not want to change the way it is used :
<IconsAdd></IconsAdd>
<IconsApps></IconsApps>
<IconsBookmark></IconsBookmark>
<IconsArrowsUp></IconsArrowsUp>

This feature is available in nuxt :

Component Names
If you have a component in nested directories such as:
-| components/
---| base/
-----| foo/
-------| Button.vue

... then the component's name will be based on its own path directory and filename, with duplicate segments being removed. Therefore, the component's name will be:
<BaseFooButton />



You likely have to get rid of "script setup" any way in favor of other syntax. How are they supposed to differ?  in a template? Then probably defining base component and using "extends" would be efficient

There is no problem in removing the setup script, but how do I apply this principle?

Please, respond to the question from the previous comment. It totally depends on what needs to be done in a component

You mean I use Options API?

Each icon has different SVG content, for example (there may be a path or more than one element), You mean I use Options API? Can you create a new answer and write what you mean?

Not necessary options api, it can work with composition https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition#extends . I cannot write an answer without knowing what you want to achieve exactly, the question contains only 1 component, it's unknown how they differ. If "script" matches 100% and "template" differs 100% then IconFoo.var is <template><svg>...</template><script>export default { extends: BaseIcon }</script>, and BaseIcon.vue uses setup()  (not "script setup") and empty 

Yes, they do share similarities in the script part but differ in the template. Thank you! I'd like to deepen my understanding: if I wanted to modify something specific in the script for one of the icons—for example, to inherit from BaseIcon.vue but also add more props or use onMounted—how would I go about that? Or if I needed to adjust something in the script, what would be the solution here? Sorry for the lengthy question, and thank you very much!

Write a new answer to benefit everyone!

Depends on the case. Sometimes it's more effective switch to options api. This includes mounted(). You need to be aware of how "extends" works to effectively use it. You can extend props. You can extend setup to some extent the docs show, it would be { extends: BaseIcon, props: { ...BaseIcon.props, foo: 1} setup(p, c) { const inst = Base.setup(p, c); let foo=ref(); return {...inst, foo }, and btw you need "setup" in child comp anyway, "extends" ignores it, and "props" may help too (I needed it once for better support of prop types in IDE)

Consider updating the question with more info that reflects your case, so it could be addressed more specifically

This always depends on the case.
extends is optimal to extend base components with some script logic being augmented and template being fully replaced, as it effectively replaces render option in this case.
Sometimes it's more effective switch to options API. This includes lifecycle hooks like mounted, they can be stacked up, according to how extends works.
Otherwise extends can be used with composition API. It extended props and other options, but doesn't affect setup, it needs to be handled manually. Props can be explicitly specified, this can useful in some cases, e.g. for better support of prop autocompletion in IDE.
setup can be composed but the variables that are local to base setup cannot be replaced due to how variable scopes work in JavaScript, this needs to be taken into account. E.g.:
BaseIcon.vue
<template></template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ...
  setup(props) {
    ...
}
</script>

IconSome.vue
<template>
<svg>...
</template>
<script>
import BaseIcon from './BaseIcon.vue'
export default {
  extends: BaseIcon,
  props: {
    ...BaseIcon.props,
    foo: ...
  },
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const instance = Base.setup(props, ctx);
    instance.bar = ref(2); // potentially bad
    let baz = ref(3); // ok if Base.setup doesn't contain baz 
    return { ...instance , baz };
  }

script setup should be avoided with extends because it's DSL and not spec-compliant JavaScript, it works in undocumented and unpredictable manner, e.g. it's known to compile to a component without render option in production, this prevents components with templates to be extended in an expected way.
